# window.postMessage method doesn't always dispatch message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a browser extension that does most of the communication via default messaging interfaces like chrome extension post connection "postMessage" and safari, "tab.dispatchMessage".

However I have some simple messages that help to identify sub-frame elements inside top frame and I don't wan't to send them to background script, I wan't to do it purely with standard window.postMessage method.

The problem is that the inner frame doesn't always get message sent from top frame. (By the time I am sending message to inner frame I am almost certain that it is loaded).

So basically my question is what up with that, and how can I make sure that my messages from top frame reach the inner frame.

**EDIT: Minimal code sample**

```
// SCRIPT WHICH IS RUNNING IN INNER FRAME
// this is where the algorithm starts 
var uuid = "unique generated id";

// STEP 4
// this is where the message send via frames[i].contentWindow.postMessage
// should be received, and this is where the problem is (it's not received sometimes, or to be more clear, not received on some pages)
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    var message = JSON.parse(event.data);
    if (message.uuid === uuid) {
        event.source.postMessage(event.data, "*");
    }
});

// STEP 1
// send identifier to top frame letting it know that inner frame
// loaded and needs to be mapped
window.top.postMessage(JSON.stringify({uuid: uuid}), "*");
```

-

```
// SCRIPT WHICH IS RUNNING IN TOP FRAME
// this script is loaded before inner frame thus is able 
// receive messages from inner frames all the time

var frames = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
var callMap = {}, frameMap = {};

// STEP 2
window.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
    var message = JSON.parse(event.data);

    // when inner frame send message with uuid but with ack
    // it needs to be mapped, the sending inner frame uuid 
    // will be sent to all frames with additional (ack) id
    if (message.uuid && !message.ack) {
        callMap[message.uuid] = {};
        for (var i = 0, len = frames.length; i < len; i++) {
            var ack = "another unique id";
            callMap[message.uuid][ack] = frames[i];
            // STEP 3
            frames[i].contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                uuid: message.uuid, ack: ack
            }), "*");
        }
    }

    if (message.ack) {
        frameMap[message.uuid] = callMap[message.uuid][message.ack];
        delete callMap[message.uuid];
    }
});
```

Comment: If you can send the message manually from devtools console when the iframe is definitely loaded, it would mean the iframe is not yet loaded in your script when you try to send a message.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions you almost always need to include your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML, and often webpage HTML/scripts. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't my code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: The reason that a [mcve] is required is that *we want to help*. It is **much** easier to help if we don't have to recreate any of the code needed to duplicate the problem. This is code that you already have. So, please help us to help you and provide a *complete* [mcve] that duplicates the problem. Without a [mcve], the amount of effort required to even begin to help you is **much** higher, which *significantly* reduces the number of people willing/able to help you. Even if we put out the extra effort, we have to **guess** at significant portions of what your problem might be.